# comparison in a time sequence

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, time, algorithm

in an Arduino sketch a user is invited to input a number representing a time in the format HH:MM,  this number is to be added at the end of an ordered and limited sequence of times

--the first input (lower limit) can be any time within the 24 hours,

--the upper limit is calculated as lower_limit+period; with period being 1,2,3,4,6,8,12 or 24 hours,

--and to be accepted, the input must verify that it is chronologically after the previous element, and that it's within the given period;

for example if first element is 20:00 and the period is 8, the upper limit will be 20+8=28 wich is 04:00; both 21:00 and 03:00 are accepted, where'is 19:00, 05:00, 09:00, 17:00, ... are rejected.

without any information on the 'day', i did not find any suitable algorithm, and none of the available Arduino libraries is useful in this case.

any link, or tip,...

Comment: Are the numbers inputted via `Serial`? On the first example, is it correct that any time from inclusive `20:01` to `04:00` will be accepted?

Comment: This smacks of homework to me....

Comment: Tip: work in minutes. The modulus (`%`) operator is your friend.

Comment: @maximilian-gerhardt: numbers are inputted via buttons... any number from 20:01 to 04:00 are accepted if it's chronologically after the last element before the upper limit...

Comment: You have numerous problems here - how to enter the times, how to convert that entered time into minutes, how to compare those times properly. Tackle it one thing at a time.

Comment: So you said you already solved the problem?

Comment: @majenko: sorry  i didn't give anough information... the only problem is how to compare those times properly...

Comment: @maximilian-gerhardt: working in minutes give a simple representation of the times but did not solve the problem... applied to the example the upper limit is still inferior to the lower limit: [20:00 to 04:00] becomes [1200 to 240]...

Comment: `if (start < end) { // check if it's greater than start *and* less than end } else { // check if it's greater than start *or* less than end }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic idea and a sample implementation for solving the problem:

The problem is: Given a start time `time1` and a period `period`, each described by a pair of `(hour,minute)`, how can we check whether another time `time2` is within `time1` to `time1 + period`?

First we can see that we given a `(hour, minute)` pair we can compute the total number of minutes as `totalMinutes = 60*hour + minute`.

Then we can observe that there two distinct cases that we must check:

- the entire "time check period", that is, `time1` to `time1 + period` is within `00:00` to `24:00` without overflowing past `24:00` when we simply add the times. then, we can use a simple bounds check worded as "`time2` must be greater than `time1` and less or equal to `time1 + period` when comparing total minnutes.
- `time1 + period` overflows past `24:00`. We consider an example of  `time1= 20:00` and `period = 8:00`. Thus all valid times are from `20:00` to `04:00` with an implicit "wrap around" at 24:00 to 00:00. We can see that there are now two time-intervals we must check: Everything from `20:01` to `24:00` and from `00:00` to `04:00` is valid. Thus we can derive the the bounds in minutes again. We can obtain the `04:00` by computing `20:00 + 08:00 modulo 24:00`. The C operator `%` is used to compute the residue of the division by a certain number. I.e. `28 % 24 = 4` because `28 / 24 = 1 residue 4`. This is  called modulo-arithmetic.

The following C++ program demonstrates the solution:

```c++
#include <cstdio>

/* returns whether time2 defined by hour2:minute2 is within the period time1 = hour1:minute1 to time1 + period. */
bool is_time_within_period(
    int hour1, int minute1, 
    int hour2, int minute2,
    int periodHour, int periodMinute) {

        //Reject garbage input
        if(hour1 > 24 || hour2 > 24 
            || minute1 > 60 || minute2 > 60
            || periodHour > 24 || periodMinute > 60) {
                //TODO throw error message
                return false;
        }

        //Convert hours and minutes into absolute minutes. One hour is 60 minutes.
        int time1Minutes = 60 * hour1  + minute1;
        int periodMinutes = 60 * periodHour + periodMinute;
        int time2Minutes  = 60 * hour2 + minute2;

        int periodEnd = time1Minutes + periodMinutes;

        //If the start time plus the period time is over 24:00 there is a wrap-around the we need to consider.
        bool wrapAround = false;
        if( periodEnd > (24 * 60)) {
            wrapAround = true;
        }

        bool result = false;

        //printf("Wrap: %d Period end %d\n", wrapAround, periodEnd);

        if(!wrapAround) {
            //if there is no wrap-around we can just compare the total minutes against each other
            //time1 must be after time2 but before (time1 + period).
            result = time2Minutes <= (time1Minutes + periodMinutes) && time2Minutes > time1Minutes;
        } else {
            //There was a wrap around, i.e. start time + period was beyond 24:00.
            //We need to make two comparisons: is it in the time period from time1Minutes to 24:00?
            result = time1Minutes < time2Minutes && time2Minutes <= (24 * 60);

            //the result can also be okay if it from the time from 00:00 to the remaining period
            //use the module operator here. This transforms e.g. 28:00 would be reduced to 04:00. (modulo 24 hours calculated in minutes)
            int upper = (periodEnd % (24 * 60));
            //printf("Upper: %d (%02d:%02d)\n", upper, (upper / 60), upper % 60);
            result |= time2Minutes >= 0 && time2Minutes <= upper;
        }

        return result;
}

int main() {

    const int hourStart = 20;
    const int minuteStart = 0;

    const int periodHours = 8;
    const int periodMinutes = 0;

    //play around with these values
    const int compareTimeHour  = 4;
    const int compareTimeMinute = 0;

    printf("Start: %02d:%02d\n", hourStart, minuteStart);
    printf("Period: %02d:%02d\n", periodHours, periodMinutes);
    printf("Check time: %02d:%02d\n", compareTimeHour, compareTimeMinute);


    bool res = is_time_within_period(hourStart, minuteStart, compareTimeHour, compareTimeMinute, periodHours, periodMinutes);

    if(res) {
        printf("Time is within bounds\n");
    } else {
        printf("Time is not within bounds\n");
    }

    printf("Hello\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The function `is_time_within_period` has no dependencies and can thus be copy-pasted into any Arduino sketch.

Let the start time be `20:00` and the period `04:00`. Then feeding the program different times to compare against lets us see that it indeed works.

```
Start: 20:00
Period: 08:00
Check time: 20:00
Time is not within bounds

Start: 20:00
Period: 08:00
Check time: 20:01
Time is within bounds

Start: 20:00
Period: 08:00
Check time: 04:00
Time is within bounds

Start: 20:00
Period: 08:00
Check time: 04:01
Time is not within bounds
```

Comment: it was very simple: if there is a wrap-around in the comparison interval; then we divide this interval in two at the point of this wrap-around... thanks and +5...

Comment: The function is_time_within_period has no dependencies and can thus be copy-pasted into any Arduino sketch.